# Python Dataframe calculate TimeDifference between Rows with different TimeStamp

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, timedelta

I want to determine the delta time between different lines in a Python Pandas DataFrame. Several lines can have the same time stamp. The delta time should then refer to the last different time.

For example:

```
   row-Number | timestamp  | expected DeltaTime
       0      |     0      |         0
       1      |    13      |         13
       2      |    13      |         13
       3      |    25      |         12
       4      |    25      |         12    
       5      |    25      |         12
```

I'm using:

```
df['delta_time_diff'] = (df['timestamp'] - df['timestamp'].shift()).fillna(0)
```

but with that I can only refer to the last line, which may not give me the desired value. The calculation with a for loop is too time intensive for long DataFrames.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
s = df['timestamp'].eq(df.timestamp.shift())
df['expected DeltaTime'] = df['timestamp'].diff().mask(s).ffill()
```

Output (different by the first timestamp, which can be fixed by `fillna`):

```
   row-Number  timestamp  expected DeltaTime
0           0          0                 NaN
1           1         13                13.0
2           2         13                13.0
3           3         25                12.0
4           4         25                12.0
5           5         25                12.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But this is not the answer for my Problem. I want to know the time difference between the last used other timestamp and my current timestamp. In this example: row-Number 3, 4 and 5 should have ```DeltaTime = 12``` and not 25.

Comment: @Christoph-W thanks for the comment. Please see update if it answers your question.